# MongoDB - Querying between a range of hours rather than dates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm writing a system to handle messaging.

One of the options of a user is DND (Do Not Disturb) where a user can define a time range where he should not be alerted (such as 22:00 - 08:00).

When I perform a query on users, I wish to filter out the users which currently are on DND.

In each user's document, I define a field to hold the time in seconds:

```
{dnd: {start: 22*3600, end: 8*3600}}
```

I'm not sure how to perform the query itself (the following sample will not work due to overlapping midnight)

```
var current; // holds current time in seconds
db.user.find({$or:[{"dnd.start":{$gt:current}},{"dnd.end":{$lt:current}}]});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach to this might be to store a "blacklist" of times as an array and query that the current time is not one of those elements. It depends on how granular you need this to be. Hours or half hours may be reasonable, as far out as per minute is not too bad.

So to generate the "blacklist" per minute you could do, as JavaScript code but the principles are easy to convert:

```js
var start = 22 * 60;
var end = 8 * 60;
var dnd = [start];
do {
    start++;
    if ( start == 1440 )
        start = 0;
    dnd.push( start );
} while ( start != end );

db.user.update({},{ "$set": { "dnd": dnd } },true)
```

Essentially setting the "blacklist" against the user record.

Then when you query for say 1:30 in the morning, or the 90th minute you would do:

```js
db.user.find({ "dnd": { "$ne": 90 })
```

And since the "blacklist" contains that value then you do not return the user records where that value would be in the list. But for a time beyond the "dnd" range it would return:

```js
db.user.find({ "dnd": { "$ne": 481 })
```

Clearly you would generally want to exclude the array element when calling up details for the user record, but that is a simple matter of projection.

Comment: If we'll reverse the comparison - it will work for this example but will fail for start=00:00 and start=01:00 for example.

Comment: @Gilad Fair enough. I have an alternate approach to this that should cover all situations.

Comment: This is a cool idea which would work, but how do I convert this list back to the actual hours (to preset to the user what were his settings?). I guess I can also save the original values to avoid recalculating every time. I'm accepting this since it does answer my question, but would still appreciate to know how to convert it back just in case :)